# Is "It is" a complete sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ellipsis, existentials

English speaker but this still gets me...

> It is

Is this a complete sentence?

Comment: Is that a complete sentence? *It is*. (Sometimes the right context can help.)

Comment: @J.R., clever, as always. ;p

Comment: **Subject**: check, **verb**: check, yup, **it's a sentence**. @J.R. +1 my teacher taught me to never define something using itself :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your example sentence is a complete sentence:

> It is.

A complete sentence must contain at least one main clause that contains an independent subject and a finite verb and has a complete meaning.

Good read about the complete sentence [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/completesentence.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It is.

Comment: A certain wickedness in me felt that this was the appropriate answer to this very question.

Comment: Especially once J.R. already answered in the comment...

Comment: But how did you defeat/evade the 30-character minimum?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock ....Touches nose and winks.....

Answer (score 0):

Such a sentence can occur as a reaction to a question such as "Is it true?"
Answer:Yes, it is.

Comment: skip the 'yes' though