# what is an "independent subject"?

Tags: grammar, terminology

I am learning the concept of *complete sentence*. An ELL post ([Is "It is" a complete sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68304/109190)) says

> A complete sentence must contain at least one main clause that contains an **independent subject** and a finite verb and has a complete meaning.

which uses a term **independent subject**, what does that mean?

I [searched on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22independent%20subject%22) and got only one hit, namely, that post itself.

I also searched on google, no luck.

So, what is an **independent subject**?

**Note**: I am aware of the concept of *subject*, I just don't know the term **independent subject**.

Comment: The poster seems to have got the expression from the site he quotes,(www.chompchomp.com/terms/completesentence.htm)

Comment: @KateBunting Yes. And I've gone through that site, didn't find a clear definition of **independent subject**.

Comment: The site just mentions 'an independent subject and verb', perhaps meaning that they are independent of one another. Don't get fixated on the phrase _independent subject_ - it isn't helpful in understanding sentence construction.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for a new aspect of reading that. And then that would lead me think about "what is the situation of dependent subject and verb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A **complete sentence** must contain at least one **main clause** that contains an **independent subject** and a finite verb and has a complete meaning.

It isn't clear, but I believe it is meant to refer to *independent clauses*.

A sentence can have multiple clauses, but it must have at least one *main* clause which should stand on its own as a complete statement.

For example:

> I was late for work this morning because my alarm clock didn't go off.

In this sentence, there are two clauses. The main clause can stand on its own as an *independent clause* because it is a complete statement:

> "I was late for work this morning".

The second clause is *dependent* on the other because it cannot stand on its own:

> "...because my alarm clock didn't go off".

Comment: I can't see the clause "My alarm clock didn't go off" cannot  stand on its own, would you please explain more about this?

Comment: @WXJ96163 You've missed the word "because". You can't have the word "because" and not give a reason. You could write the sentence this way around: "Because my alarm clock didn't go off I was late for work". The first clause would still be dependent.